# Access control based on a connected app

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps

I would like to redirect incoming oauth token requests from a certain connected app, to perform additional access control for that specific app before granting it the access token, or at least before granting it API access.

Would it be possible to customize the instanceUrl returned by login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token for my instance, for specific connected apps (or for all)?

Can this be done with some Apex code (such as Auth providers or similar), or via the Salesforce Setup UI?

Alternatively, can I configure a redirect from login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token to an URL under my control (can be under SF or external)?

Comment: _perform additional access control for that specific app_ is beyond the responsibility of oAuth authorization service (Salesforce/connected app). One approach: you develop your own app that talks to SF via [headless auth code & credentials API](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.headless_identity_customers_overview.htm&type=5), then orchestrate in your app whatever additional access control you need.

Comment: @identigral with this approach, would it be possible to impose additional access control on third party connected apps, or just on my app?

Comment: Your connected app. 3rd party SF connected apps are no different from non-SF apps that you interact with via oAuth.